# Hibernate ManyToOne Association Error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have been trying all day to achieve an easy ForeignKey ManyToOne Association in Java / JPA (Hibernate) ... without success. Now it really is time to ask for help;-)

I have two database tables as follows:

Please have a look here:

[image: http://okas-net.de/tutos/html/datamodel.jpg]

And objects like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sa_s_cat")
public class SCat implements Serializable {

@Id
private int catId;
private String catSuffix;
private String catDesc;
private Lkzs lkz;
private Date cdate;
private String cuser;
...
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sa_s_subcat")
public class SSubCat implements Serializable {

@Id
private int subcatId;
private int catId;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "catId")
private SCat cat;
private String subcatSuffix;
private String subcatDesc;
private boolean subcatShowProd;
private boolean subcatShowComp;
private boolean subcatShowQual;
private boolean subcatShowDetail;
private Lkzs lkz;
private Date cdate;
private String cuser;
...
```

And I receive this errormessage:

```
...
2014-07-11 09:16:32,649 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl - configure() - JDBC version : 4.0
2014-07-11 09:16:32,665 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.cursor.internal.StandardRefCursorSupport - supportsRefCursors() - JDBC DatabaseMetaData class does not define supportsRefCursors method...
```

...

In the meantime, I have searched many forums, read documentations and tutorials ... therefore that should actually work.

Comment: Post the **complete** stack trace of the exception.

Comment: looks like a configuration problem trying to connect to your database

Comment: @JB Nizet: Stack trace shows no other Errors?!

Comment: @TritonMan: Configuration and Connection to database is OK. I can retrieve subcat and cat without Problems. But soon as I integrate the foreignkey-association the error appers.

Comment: That isn't really a stack trace you posted. It's just the debug output in the console. The full stack trace will show class names and line numbers pin pointing where the error occurred and have a description of the error. Besides, the ... at the end implies there's more.

Comment: this should actually work , What are the versions of Hibernate core and entity manager ?

Comment: @BenThurley: I'm sorry, but there are no more stacktraces because there are no more exceptions. The "..." is just because I can't put the complete debug Output in the post - it's too Long ;-) Are there any ways to get further Information of the last error in eclipse?

Comment: @ShadowRay: Hibernate EntitiyManager = 4.3.5.Final. Hibernate Core is not used ...

Comment: You've missed a stack trace somewhere in the console. I imagine somewhere during startup. If you scroll back through you'll probably see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a Long Phase of Trial and error I found a solution.

I deleted the foreign key definition from database and changed the code as followed:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sa_s_cat")
public class SCat implements Serializable {

@Id
private int catId;
private String catSuffix;
private String catDesc;
private Lkzs lkz;
private Date cdate;
private String cuser;
...
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sa_s_subcat")
public class SSubCat implements Serializable {

@Id
private int subcatId;
private int catId;
private String subcatSuffix;
private String subcatDesc;
private boolean subcatShowProd;
private boolean subcatShowComp;
private boolean subcatShowQual;
private boolean subcatShowDetail;
private Lkzs lkz;
private Date cdate;
private String cuser;
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "catId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private SCat cat;
...
```

But this leads me to some further questions, which I hope someone can explain to me:

1. Must there be foreign keys defined in database to achieve mapping with hibernate/JPA or can I do the mapping only in code - which I would prefer?
2. Is the above mentioned solution JPA-conformant? (I don't think so ;-)
3. And of course, why is this "solution" working?

Comment: What do you mean mapping only in code? There needs to be something to link them in the DB. How else can JPA work out which rows are related? You don't need to specify that foreign key column as a field in the entity though. You just need to name it as the join column on your many to one relationship.

Comment: In fact, that's your problem. If you specify the catId foreign key column as a field in the entity + also name it as a join column on the many to one then effectively you've mapped that same DB column to two fields in your entity. This is why insertable, updateable fixed it, because it tells JPA to not worry about persisting the many to one field so for persists it will save the value in catId, not cat.

Comment: @BenThurley: That's exactly what I wanted. JPA should not worry about persisting. (Also I had "NoAction" on persist and update defined on the foreign key.) I only need the association for displaying the associated cat. Many thanks.

Comment: You're really going against the grain. JPA is an ORM tool designed to map objects to relational databases. If you map the object you can still get the id by doing something like getSCat().getId() instead of getCatId().

Answer (score 0):

**Map objects not columns**
The problem is that you've effectively mapped the same DB column (the catId foreign key) to two fields in your entity. You've mapped it directly as a primitive int as catId and also mapped the object relationship as SCat cat.

In JPA you have to try to forget the DB implementation and think in objects. An SSubCat *has a* SCat, ok so add a field of type SCat to SSubCat. Now on the annotations you think about how this is done in the database. You have a foreign key column called catId, this you specify with the @JoinColumn.

If you try to specify both the primitive column and object relationship then JPA doesn't know which to choose when persisting the object. As you've found out, one way to rectify this would be to specify one of those fields as not insertable or updateable. JPA will populate both when it retrieves from the database but when you save back to the DB it will only save the value for the field that is still updateable.

One other problem with having two fields for the one column like this is that they'll quickly get out of sync. If you call setCat to change the SCat object then the catId will still be the id for the old SCat. You would have to add manual code in the setter to keep both fields in sync. You don't really want this unless you have some weird requirement that means you absolutely have to. You probably don't, just map the objects.

**Bi-Directional one to many**
Using JPA it's more usual to map as a bi-directional relationship like the following.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sa_s_cat")
public class SCat implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private int catId;

  // mappedBy = the field in the other class that is the ManyToOne side
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="cat")
  private List<SSubCat> subCategories;


@Entity
@Table(name = "sa_s_subcat")
public class SSubCat implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private int subcatId;

  // The join column is the foreign key column in the DB
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "catId")
  private SCat cat;
```

**Uni-Directional one to many**
You say you want a uni-directional @ManyToOne. Since this is only mapped on one side of the relationship then in theory you need to tell JPA the column names from both tables (unless the columns have the same name in both tables - in your case they do but I've specified both here to show how). Assuming you're using JPA 2.0 and you've checked that your provider supports this... then you'll need something like this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sa_s_subcat")
public class SSubCat implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private int subcatId;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="catId", referencedColumnName="catId")
  private SCat cat;
```

Tbh though I would go for the bi-directional relationship.

Comment: Thanks but as far as I know, the relationship in both entities is only necessary if you want to have biderectional association. But Unidirectional is what I want. (ForeignKey column in DB is "catId")          I tried your Suggestion and added onetomany in cat ... same behavior. Thx anyway!

Comment: you don't have to tell the JPA the column names for both tables when you are using unidirectional.

Comment: Have a read of this http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Undirectional_OneToMany.2C_No_Inverse_ManyToOne.2C_No_Join_Table_.28JPA_2.0_ONLY.29

Comment: I tested with your unidirectional example, but same behavior. I updated the trace in the post above. I read the wikibook already. Same thing written there, but it won't work ...

Comment: @ShadowRay you don't need to specify both column names if they are the same, which in this case they are. If they have different names then you must name them both using the name and referencedColumnName attributes. It doesn't do any harm to name both though.